# Stress on "can" and "could"

Tags: modal-verbs, speech, stress

> - I can go there.
> - I could go there.

In these sentences, when spoken, how is the meaning altered by putting stress/emphasis on the words *can* and *could*?

Comment: Please use the tools and techniques I taught you in your previous question to improve the legibility of this question. Presentation matters; when people encounter an unreadable wall of I formatted text, they are as apt as not to abandon the question and not return.

Comment: Does "give emphatic on" mean 'contrastively stress'? That's the only sense I can make of the question.

Comment: Yes, I went there.

Comment: It simply means that you're contradicting any possible statement that you can't or couldn't go there. There's no semantic difference, only a pragmatic difference in how strongly you express the meaning. And btw, this has nothing to do with _can_ or _could_ -- any word in a sentence can be contrastively stressed.

Answer (score 1):

Without stress, saying "I can go there" or "I could go there" means that going there is within your capability, and implies you probably will.

With stress, saying "I *can* go there" or "I *could* go there" means that although going there is within your capability, you probably will choose to *not* exercise that option.

Comment: Also, to me, stressing _can_ implies that you want (better) compensation for going there, while stressing _could_ implies that you don't **really** want to go there and is prepared to provide excuses.

Answer (score 0):

"I *can* go there" contradicts a suggestion that you can't go there.  "I *could* go there" implies that you won't go there, even though you could.  Since "could" has an interpretation "used to be able to", another way of construing "I *could* go there" is that it implies you can't go there any longer, even though you used to be able to.

These interpretations follow from (1) the fact that strong stress is often contrastive, so there is something to contrast the emphasized word with, and (2) when you say something, there should be some point to what you are saying.

I suppose there are other interpretations possible, but these are the first that came to mind.

Comment: "You *can* go there" might very well imply that you *shouldn't*.  It depends on the context.  "You *could* go there" might often be used when "there" is an option, but a better one is about to be suggested or inferred.

Answer (score -1):

Can or Could?
A modal auxiliary verb or a helping verb is used to modify the mood of the verb. It is important to know that these “modal verbs” have no meaning by themselves.

Can: is used to express ability, willingness, permission, or possibility. The negative form of can is  “cannot” or the contraction “can’t”.

Could: has at least three key functions:
1) It can replace “can” to give more conditional tone to a phrase.
2)It is used as a past tense of “can”.
3)It can function as suggesting that something is a possibility.

For more details and practice: visit
https://www.biglearners.com/worksheets/grade-4/english/grammar/use-modal-auxiliaries